# Get $PIPESTATUS inside a pipe

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell

I use a bash-script to check the output of cron-jobs:

> some-cron-script.sh | check_pipe.sh

check_pipe.sh reads the pipe and if it finds defined keywords (like 'error' or 'failed') inside, it sends an email.
Now I would like to check also the exit-status of the first script in check_pipe.sh. Unfortunately, ${PIPESTATUS[@]} is not yet set when check_pipe.sh is executed. If I ask PIPESTATUS after the pipe in a new command, two values are given - but for me too late. Any help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Store the output in a variable (if it's not too large, see [shell variable capacity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5076283/10765659)):

```
output=$(some-script)
status=$? check-pipe <<<"$output"   # warning: <<< is not POSIX
unset output
```

Alternatively use a (temporary) file:

```
some-script >file
status=$? check-pipe <file
rm file
```

In both cases `check-pipe` gets the output of `some-script` via stdin plus the exit status as `status` environment variable. The two commands don't run in parallel.